# Set up digits in input with Jquery

Tags: jquery

In fields `input` I have some digits like `14358437`.

How I can change it with jQuery to set this queries like `14`

Comment: Please elaborate a little as to what you want. I'm sure I can help you.

Comment: I need to. Please tell me how to.

Comment: Please be more **specific** to what is your question. You want to put the value of `14` in every `input` field? Or do you want to round the value of each `input` to the first two digits?

Comment: I want to round the value of each input to the first two digits (millions). Language knowledges bad to discribe

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b7k3a96k/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input').val($('input').val().substring(0, 2));
    });
```

Comment: Cool! This work. Thanks a lot. And one more question: a have two inputs "from 2234255 millions" to "1429298834 millions". Your code change all inputs values like in first inputs and no differnce between them

Comment: look at this http://jsfiddle.net/b7k3a96k/1/ @user2896218

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').val(14);
```

If you want to put the value "14" in every input on the page.

Comment: Hm. The values could be any queries 1234566, 3209403. But all of inputs are millions